# Database Wrapper Class for Python

Tags: python, database

I am a PHP developer and recently migrated to Python. In PHP, there are many classes available at for example phpclasses.org which saves a lot of developer's time. I am looking for similar kind of repository for python. I need a database wrapper class for accessing the database with python. One of the class i found was at http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/22093 . But i didnt find any other similar class. So i m wondering no one in this world has created such kind of classes. Is there any better approach to access database in Python. Am i on the wrong track? I m aware of the ORM and its advantage but for small projects it doesnt make sense to me to use ORM's. Can anyone suggest some suitable python database wrapper class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not to burst your bubble, but why don't you use a nifty framework like web2py, Django and the likings. That would avoid going in such a low level.

Comment: There is SQLAlchemy, while it's ORM it usually requires very little setup. I have used it in small scripts myself. But each to their own :)

Comment: Thankyou guys for your suggestion.
@Tudorizer I agree to you than un-intentionally i was going in such a low level.

Answer (score 3):

Following Skurmedel's advice, I remembered reading about SQLAlchemy before. It's pretty well documented and maintained. Here's a good start point: [SQLAlchemy 1.4 / 2.0 Tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Most databases you choose to use will have a module available that conforms to the [DBAPI](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). That gives you access that is quite easy to use and reasonably portable across different types of database (though not entirely). You can see an example of the API in action with the [built-in SQLite support](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

If you'll reconsider your opposition to ORMs however, as well as SQLAlchemy mentioned in another answer, [SQLObject](http://www.sqlobject.org/) is another ORM, and is very simple to use. There's also [Storm](https://storm.canonical.com/).